# Join two children

Tags: c#, xml, xpath

I have this XML File:

```
<library>
    <book ISBN="BSWE153" authors = "AC532" >
        <title>Leraing XML</title>
        <year>1995</year>
        <publisher>W3C</publisher>
    </book>

    <author id="AC532">
        <firstName>Hamdy</firstName>
        <middleName/>
        <lastName>Taha</lastName>
        <nationality>Egypatian</nationality>
    </author>
</library>
```

How to print the information of a book (with its authors information) given by its ISBN?

Comment: In what language? What have you tried so far?

Comment: ... and what means *print* in your context?

Comment: What have you tried? In which programming language are you using to address this issue? python/java/xsl/..

Comment: I use C# with DataSet

Comment: The title is almost as good as one of those from the Arcade.SE

Answer (score 0):

You can do that using [`XDocument`](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.xml.linq.xdocument(v=vs.110).aspx), for example. You will need to

1. Parse your string (or load the file)
2. locate the book
3. read author Id (or ids?)
4. locate the author
5. nicely format it all together - with appropriate checks.

that is just a sketch:

```
const string xml = @"<?xml version=""1.0""?>
<library>
    <book ISBN=""BSWE153"" authors = ""AC532"" >
        <title>Leraing XML</title>
        <year>1995</year>
        <publisher>W3C</publisher>
    </book>

    <author id=""AC532"">
        <firstName>Hamdy</firstName>
        <middleName/>
        <lastName>Taha</lastName>
        <nationality>Egypatian</nationality>
    </author>
</library>
";

var doc = XDocument.Parse(xml); 

var book = doc.Root.Elements("book")
            .FirstOrDefault(b => (string)b.Attribute("ISBN") == "BSWE153" );
var authorId = book.Attribute("authors").Value.ToString();

var author = doc.Root.Elements("author")
            .FirstOrDefault(b => (string)b.Attribute("id") == authorId );

Console.WriteLine("{0} by {1} {2}",     
                book.Element("title").Value,
                author.Element("firstName").Value,
                author.Element("lastName").Value);
```